# Remote access to Android Phone including Voice

Tags: android, remote-access

I've been googling for some time, and I've found various apps to control an android phone to some extent, however none that I have found allow what I would control full control.

The main features I am after is the ability to answer the phone and sms over the internet (preferably over an enycrpyted connection) anybody any thoughts?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What are your "full requirements" (not just the "main" ones)? Any budget, or must it be free? For a starter, you might wish to see my app-list on [Control your Droid from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid) as well :)

Comment: Thanks several options on there would solve the SMS side of things, any ideas on answering and making calls remotely?

Comment: *Initiating* calls would be easy (i.e. dial from your PC, but have the call itself on the Android device). But *responding* to incoming calls I don't know. Have you checked these as well: [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement) (linked from the first)? Looks like [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) might fit: "handle calls from your desktop, dial numbers, accept, reject and end calls". Needs a Windows-companion application though.